# How do I add a div to DOM and pick it up later

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

I think this is specific to IE 6.0 but...

In JavaScript I add a `div` to the DOM. I assign an `id` attribute. When I later try to pick up the `div` by the `id` all I get is `null`.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
newDiv.setAttribute("ID", "obj_1000");
document.appendChild(newDiv);

alert("Added:" + newDiv.getAttribute("ID") + ":" + newDiv.id + ":" + document.getElementById("obj_1000") );
```

Alert prints `"::null"`

Seems to work fine in Firefox 2.0+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what the other answers suggest (that you need to actually insert the element into the DOM for it to be found via `getElementById()`), you also need to use a lower-case attribute name in order for IE6 to recognize it as the `id`:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV"); 
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "obj_1000");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

alert("Added:"
   + newDiv.getAttribute("id") 
   + ":" + newDiv.id + ":" 
   + document.getElementById("obj_1000") );
```

...responds as expected:

```
Added:obj_1000:obj_1000:[object]
```

---

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536739(VS.85).aspx) for `setAttribute()`, up to IE8 there is an optional *third parameter* that controls whether or not it is case sensitive with regard to the attribute name. Guess what the default is...

Answer (score 3):

The div needs to be added to an element for it to be part of the document.

```
document.appendChild(newDiv);

alert( document.getElementById("obj_1000") );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the div to the dom.

```
// Create the Div
var oDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(oDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

newDiv.setAttribute( "ID", "obj_1000" );

should be

newDiv.id = "obj_1000";

Answer (score 0):

Hummm, thanks for putting me on the right track guys...this was odd but it turns out that if I change the case to lower case, everything starting working just fine...

Finished Result:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "obj_1000");
document.appendChild(newDiv);

alert("Added:" +
      newDiv.getAttribute("id") + ":" +
      newDiv.id + ":" +
      document.getElementById("obj_1000"));
```

ODD...VERY ODD